# Issue in Title bar Customization

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I have created a customized title. The supported xmls are

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <resources> 
    <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground" /> 
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme"> 
     <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dp</item>
     <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground
     </item>
    </style> 
 </resources>
```

customtitle.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="@color/grey7"
    android:startColor="@color/black" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="12dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
    android:topRightRadius="12dp" >
</corners>

</shape>
```

The resultant title bar should be rounded from four corners but it is only rounded on top left and top right.
How to make it rounded on all corners???

Comment: try  after changing android:startColor="@color/black" black to red

Comment: can i post it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use android:background to control the round effect:
for example:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="@color/bar_more_main_start"
        android:endColor="@color/bar_more_main_end" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="6dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="6dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="6dip"
        android:topRightRadius="6dip" />

</shape>
```